# What are these white specks on this osteospermum (african daisy)?

Tags: identification, pests, pest-damage, damage

This african daisy plant has lots of tiny white "crystals" of varying sizes all over the soil and stem, with some on top of the leaves as well (not as much underneath). It looks a lot like salt. Some of the leaves were chewed on by something, the end of one stem is brown/dying, and there's a really thin spiderweb at the top (upper right photo). This plant was a gift, so I don't know how it was taken care of before. I thought it might be spider mites, although I don't see anything moving, but I'd like to make sure before I bring it back indoors. What could this be?

[image: white specks and leaf damage]

Comment: They look more like marigolds (*Tagetes*) to me. If you see small spider webs (I can't see them very good on the photo), they may indeed be spider mites.

Comment: This absolutely does not look like spider mites to me, I think it is fungus due to not well-draining soil. You can introduce more light and less water and see if the problem goes away.